# Removing Items from an ArrayList through a JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, error-handling, jtable

I have a `JTable` that includes items from an `ArrayList`, however whenever I try to remove the contents of deleted row from the `ArrayList` I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` depending on the amount of rows I wanted to delete and their location. How would I go about solving this issue?

Runnable Code: http://pastebin.com/Nnrnxzdg

```
remove.addActionListener( e -> {
    int k = 0;
    int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
    TableModel tm= table.getModel();
    while(rows.length>0)
    { 
        while(k<rows.length)
        {
            al.remove(table.getSelectedRow() + k);
            k++;
         }   
         ((DefaultTableModel)tm).removeRow(table.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[0]));

         rows = table.getSelectedRows();
     }
     table.clearSelection();
});
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: index from al.remove  <> tm.emoveRow, is strange to removing the same element from two different arrays, use array as major data for aplication (abstracttablemodel with implemented array) or use tablemodel as major data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the moment you remove a row, all the indices change.  So what you need to do, is make a copy of all the selected rows, but NOT the index, but the actual row value...

```
JTable table = getTable();
if (table.getSelectedRowCount() > 0) {
    List<Vector> selectedRows = new ArrayList<>(25);
    DefaultTableModel model = getModel();
    Vector rowData = model.getDataVector();
    for (int row : table.getSelectedRows()) {
        int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        Vector rowValue = (Vector) rowData.get(modelRow);
        selectedRows.add(rowValue);
    }
```

Now with this, you can calculate the `indexOf` any given object with the model and remove it...

```
    for (Vector rowValue : selectedRows) {
        int rowIndex = rowData.indexOf(rowValue);
        model.removeRow(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

without caring what the index of the value was.

Comment: Good general purpose solution for DefaultTableModel that will work for sorted and filtered tables (+1).

Answer (score 3):

The indexes change if you remove the rows from the start of the model.

One solution is to remove one row at a time, ten all the selected indexes are reset so you are always removing the proper index:

Here is an example showing how you might do this for a JList and a JTable:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ItemDeletion extends JPanel
{
    private JList<String> list;
    private JTable table;

    public ItemDeletion()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );

        String[] items =
        {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten"
        };

        //  Add the list

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        for (String item: items)
            listModel.addElement( item );

        list = new JList<String>( listModel );


        JButton listDelete = new JButton( "Delete From List" );
        listDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
                int row = list.getSelectedIndex();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    model.removeElementAt( row );
                    row = list.getSelectedIndex();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        listPanel.add(new JScrollPane( list ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        listPanel.add(listDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add the table

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
        List<String> tableItems = Arrays.asList( items );
        Collections.shuffle( tableItems );

        for (String item: tableItems)
        {
            System.out.println( item );
            tableModel.addRow( new String[]{item} );
        }

        table = new JTable( tableModel );

        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).toggleSortOrder(0);

        JButton tableDelete = new JButton( "Delete From Table" );
        tableDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel( row );
                    model.removeRow( modelRow );
                    row = table.getSelectedRow();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tablePanel.add(tableDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multiple Item Deletion");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ItemDeletion(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Reversing the indices was going to be my other suggestion +1